# Model is not reflected when I use same controller with two divs

Tags: angularjs

I have given same controller in two divs but model that gets updated in   one div does not reflect in another.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="filterCtrl">
        <p ng-bind="test" />
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="filterCtrl">
        <p><input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="handleChange()"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I am entering into the text box it's not updating the above div's "ng--bind". Though, if I put that "ng-bind" in the div having text box, it's working fine. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: why you define the controller twice

Comment: Because when you are creating same controller twice in different div it will create two different instance of same controller and ng-model is belongs to same controller in which you are declaring and thats why it is not reflecting in other controller.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like that

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <body ng-controller="filterCtrl">
        <div>
            <p>{{test.text}}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p><input type="text" ng-model="test.text" ng-change="handleChange()"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QENnm8c7RmC5DaSIsmiN?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing bad to reuse controller in your code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/0vvgebq5/)

As you can see they both works, but independently.
It's because each other instantiate its own scope. If you want them to talk, you can to make it via some services or to create some common scope for both of them, or merge them into one controller instance.

You can use parent scope as common part for both.

```
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrlr as c">
      <input ng-model="$parent.name" />
       Hello, {{$parent.name}}!!!
  </div>  
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrlr as c">
      <input ng-model="$parent.name" />
       Hello, {{$parent.name}}!!!
  </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/0vvgebq5/1/)

---

Talk via services will be much better than this:

Code:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrlr', ['MainData', function(MD){
  this.MD = MD;
  MD.name = 'World';
}]).service('MainData', [function(){}])
```

Template:

```
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrlr as c">
      <input ng-model="c.MD.name" />
       Hello, {{c.MD.name}}!!!
  </div>  
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrlr as c">
      <input ng-model="c.MD.name" />
       Hello, {{c.MD.name}}!!!
  </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/0vvgebq5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:

If we try to associate same controller with two divs then angular creates two different scopes for those two divs.
And if we try to update scope in one instance then it will not be reflected to other instance.

There are two ways to get rid of from this situation:

1. You can create one mainCntrl that have filterCtrl as its child controller.
   And assumed mainCntrl has mainView scope property. We created a mainView object on the mainCntrl, 
   and since filterCtrl and its scope prototypally inherit from mainCntrl so we can always reach that mainView in any instance of filterCtrl.

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <html>
     <head>
      
      <script>
       angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller('mainCntrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.mainView = {};
        $scope.mainView.x = 'Something';
       })
       .controller('filterCtrl', function($scope) {
       });
      </script>
     </head>
     <body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="mainCntrl">
       <div ng-controller="filterCtrl">
        <p ng-bind="mainView.x" />
       </div>
       <div ng-controller="filterCtrl">
        <p><input type="text" ng-model="mainView.x" ng-change="handleChange()"></p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

2. We can utilized $parent which can be accessed through $scope.$parent. This place will be the common place for all the instances of filterCtrl.
   So whatever we put over $scope.$parent, will be accissible to all the instances.

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
       <html>
     <head>
      <script>
       angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller('filterCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.$parent.test = 'Something';
       });
      </script>
     </head>
     <body ng-app="myApp">
       <div ng-controller="filterCtrl">
        <p ng-bind="$parent.test" />
       </div>
       <div ng-controller="filterCtrl">
        <p><input type="text" ng-model="$parent.test" ng-change="handleChange()"></p>
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```